# Get resource object by a strong-typed key

Tags: c#, localization, resources, resx

I've been getting resource objects like this:

```
    public string GetLocalizedTerm(Type resource, string key, string culture)
    {
        System.Resources.ResourceManager rm = new System.Resources.ResourceManager(resource);
        return rm.GetString(key, culture);
    }

    //tests
    string valueInEnglish = this.GetLocalizedTerm(typeof(LocalizedStrings), "ProductNumber", "en");
    string valueInGerman = this.GetLocalizedTerm(typeof(LocalizedStrings), "ProductNumber", "de");
```

Works well, but we started to make some changes in the resources files resx, so it's more complicated to find all the terms in the application with a key as string.

Is there a way to pass the key but not as a string, but as it's strong-typed form?

I mean something like this:

```
    public string GetLocalizedTerm(Type resource, string key, string culture)
    {
        System.Resources.ResourceManager rm = new System.Resources.ResourceManager(resource);
        return rm.GetString(key, culture);
    }

    // Resources.Localization.LocalizedStrings 
    //tests
    string valueInEnglish = this.GetLocalizedTerm(typeof(LocalizedStrings), Resources.Localization.LocalizedStrings.ProductNumber, "en");
    string valueInGerman = this.GetLocalizedTerm(typeof(LocalizedStrings), Resources.Localization.LocalizedStrings.ProductNumber, "de");
```

In that way if the resource file changes, the terms will be easily detectable at design time.

Comment: You could use the `nameof` operator like this: `nameof(LocalizedStrings.ProductNumber)` to get "ProductNumber". If someone changed the resource name it would fail to compile.

Comment: The more I learn about things like nameof() the more I feel the need to upgrade projects to c# 6...

Comment: @mikez that's an awesome feature that I discover yesterday. But we are still using C# 5 with FX 4.5. We cannot upgrade immediately in production server. Is there something equivalent in C# 5.0?